# How to configure the JWT token in django-graphql-jwt to obtain the userId in the token instead of just the username?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-graphql-jwt

**TLDR** - But by default the JWT token sent from the backend only includes the username. I want the userId as well.This is what it contains currently:-

```
HEADER:ALGORITHM & TOKEN TYPE

{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "HS256"
}
PAYLOAD:DATA

{
  "username": "admin",  <---- I have the username already. Need the userId as well!
  "exp": 1621845856,
  "origIat": 1621845556
}
VERIFY SIGNATURE

HMACSHA256(
  base64UrlEncode(header) + "." +
  base64UrlEncode(payload),
  
your-256-bit-secret

) secret base64 encoded
```

I have a Django GraphQL API (using Graphene, django-graphql-auth, django-graphql-jwt) and an Angular frontend. I have authentication setup fully. Now the issue I'm facing is that I'm storing the token in the localstorage and so when the user opens the browser again, I want to verify that token and use just the information in there to obtain the user's id and then use that userId to fetch their user profile information, which is an essential step to complete the login process.

I am not sure how to customize the payload to include the userId as well. So that when the user opens the browser after shutting down, I can simply use just the information in the token to fully log them in. I'm very new to both Python and Django. I couldn't find the process detailed anywhere online, maybe I wasn't looking for the right thing or in the right place. Detailed instructions would be very helpful.

Comment: you could customize, the jwt_payload. It is mentioned in this issue https://github.com/flavors/django-graphql-jwt/issues/86

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is a more thorough reproduction of solution found [here](https://github.com/flavors/django-graphql-jwt/issues/86#issuecomment-474610504).

We basically need to override the jwt_payload method that comes as part of the `graphql_jwt` package.

Add this to project's `settings.py`

```
GRAPHQL_JWT = {
    'JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER': 'common.utils.jwt_payload',
}
```

Create the following files in a folder `common` in the same directory where you have the `manage.py` file.

Inside, create the following two files:-
Here's where we're adding the user_id in the `sub` attribute.

utils.py

```
from calendar import timegm
from datetime import datetime
from .settings import jwt_settings


def jwt_payload(user, context=None):
    username = user.get_username()
    user_id = str(user.id)

    if hasattr(username, 'pk'):
        username = username.pk

    payload = {
        user.USERNAME_FIELD: username,
        'sub': user_id,
        'exp': datetime.utcnow() + jwt_settings.JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA,
    }

    if jwt_settings.JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH:
        payload['origIat'] = timegm(datetime.utcnow().utctimetuple())

    if jwt_settings.JWT_AUDIENCE is not None:
        payload['aud'] = jwt_settings.JWT_AUDIENCE

    if jwt_settings.JWT_ISSUER is not None:
        payload['iss'] = jwt_settings.JWT_ISSUER

    return payload
```

This settings.py file inside the common folder is just a dependency. for the utils.py.

settings.py

```
from datetime import timedelta
from importlib import import_module

from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.test.signals import setting_changed

DEFAULTS = {
    'JWT_ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'JWT_AUDIENCE': None,
    'JWT_ISSUER': None,
    'JWT_LEEWAY': 0,
    'JWT_SECRET_KEY': settings.SECRET_KEY,
    'JWT_VERIFY': True,
    'JWT_VERIFY_EXPIRATION': False,
    'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': timedelta(seconds=60 * 5),
    'JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH': True,
    'JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DELTA': timedelta(days=7),
    'JWT_LONG_RUNNING_REFRESH_TOKEN': False,
    'JWT_REFRESH_TOKEN_MODEL': 'refresh_token.RefreshToken',
    'JWT_REFRESH_TOKEN_N_BYTES': 20,
    'JWT_AUTH_HEADER_NAME': 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION',
    'JWT_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX': 'JWT',
    'JWT_ALLOW_ARGUMENT': False,
    'JWT_ARGUMENT_NAME': 'token',
    'JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER': 'graphql_jwt.utils.jwt_encode',
    'JWT_DECODE_HANDLER': 'graphql_jwt.utils.jwt_decode',
    'JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER': 'graphql_jwt.utils.jwt_payload',
    'JWT_PAYLOAD_GET_USERNAME_HANDLER': (
        lambda payload: payload.get(get_user_model().USERNAME_FIELD)
    ),
    'JWT_GET_USER_BY_NATURAL_KEY_HANDLER':
    'graphql_jwt.utils.get_user_by_natural_key',
    'JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRED_HANDLER': 'graphql_jwt.utils.refresh_has_expired',
    'JWT_GET_REFRESH_TOKEN_HANDLER':
    'graphql_jwt.refresh_token.utils.get_refresh_token_by_model',
    'JWT_ALLOW_ANY_HANDLER': 'graphql_jwt.middleware.allow_any',
    'JWT_ALLOW_ANY_CLASSES': (),
    'JWT_COOKIE_NAME': 'JWT',
    'JWT_REFRESH_TOKEN_COOKIE_NAME': 'JWT-refresh-token',
    'JWT_COOKIE_SECURE': False,
}

IMPORT_STRINGS = (
    'JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER',
    'JWT_DECODE_HANDLER',
    'JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER',
    'JWT_PAYLOAD_GET_USERNAME_HANDLER',
    'JWT_GET_USER_BY_NATURAL_KEY_HANDLER',
    'JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRED_HANDLER',
    'JWT_GET_REFRESH_TOKEN_HANDLER',
    'JWT_ALLOW_ANY_HANDLER',
    'JWT_ALLOW_ANY_CLASSES',
)


def perform_import(value, setting_name):
    if isinstance(value, str):
        return import_from_string(value, setting_name)
    if isinstance(value, (list, tuple)):
        return [import_from_string(item, setting_name) for item in value]
    return value


def import_from_string(value, setting_name):
    try:
        module_path, class_name = value.rsplit('.', 1)
        module = import_module(module_path)
        return getattr(module, class_name)
    except (ImportError, AttributeError) as e:
        msg = 'Could not import `{}` for JWT setting `{}`. {}: {}.'.format(
            value, setting_name, e.__class__.__name__, e,
        )
        raise ImportError(msg)


class JWTSettings:

    def __init__(self, defaults, import_strings):
        self.defaults = defaults
        self.import_strings = import_strings
        self._cached_attrs = set()

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if attr not in self.defaults:
            raise AttributeError('Invalid setting: `{}`'.format(attr))

        value = self.user_settings.get(attr, self.defaults[attr])

        if attr == 'JWT_ALLOW_ANY_CLASSES':
            value = list(value) + [
                'graphql_jwt.mixins.JSONWebTokenMixin',
                'graphql_jwt.mixins.VerifyMixin',
                'graphql_jwt.refresh_token.mixins.RevokeMixin',
            ]

        if attr in self.import_strings:
            value = perform_import(value, attr)

        self._cached_attrs.add(attr)
        setattr(self, attr, value)
        return value

    @property
    def user_settings(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_user_settings'):
            self._user_settings = getattr(settings, 'GRAPHQL_JWT', {})
        return self._user_settings

    def reload(self):
        for attr in self._cached_attrs:
            delattr(self, attr)

        self._cached_attrs.clear()

        if hasattr(self, '_user_settings'):
            delattr(self, '_user_settings')


def reload_settings(*args, **kwargs):
    setting = kwargs['setting']

    if setting == 'GRAPHQL_JWT':
        jwt_settings.reload()


setting_changed.connect(reload_settings)

jwt_settings = JWTSettings(DEFAULTS, IMPORT_STRINGS)
```